Error in R powerSim function for a fixed effect in a LMM
I have a LMM with 2 categorical fixed factors (ffactor1, ffactor2), a random factor (id), and a covariate of no interest (baseline). I am trying to estimate the power using R's powerSim function. I am specifically interested in ffactor2, and if possible I want to use bootstrapping. I am getting errors, what am I doing wrong?
I run:
mymodel <- lmer(Y ~ baseline + ffactor1*ffactor2 + (1|id), data=data)
p <- powerSim(mymodel, nsim=50, test = fixed(xname="ffactor2",method = "pb"))
p

I get:
Power for predictor 'ffactor2', (95% confidence interval):
       0.00% ( 0.00,  7.11)

Test: Parametric bootstrap (package pbkrtest)

Based on 50 simulations, (0 warnings, 50 errors)
alpha = 0.05, nrow = NA

Time elapsed: 0 h 0 m 0 s

nb: result might be an observed power calculation

Have you checked mymodel to confirm that it looks complete and reasonable? Did you get any warnings/errors when you ran lmer(.)? powerSim isn't base R, do you mean simR::powerSim?

Yes, my model seems ok to me, and yes, I mean sir:powerSim (sorry for not clarifying this earlier). Thank you!
